# Display Nodes from Taxonomy Category Term and Parent Terms

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I am using Views and Drupal Commerce but not sure this should matter as all my products are also nodes. I have a taxonomy hierarchy for categories. Example

```
Exterior Accessories
|_ Top
   |_ Soft Tops
   |_ Hard Tops
|_ Bottoms
   |_ Right Bottoms
   |_ Left Bottoms
```

I can easily make a page that shows me the Hard Tops if on that location or Soft Tops if at that location. But is what i can not for the life of me  figure out how to do is if I click on TOP I want to see Soft Tops and Hard Tops, and if I click on Exterior Accessories I want it to show products that are from any of the child elements with unlimited depth. So when viewing one of these pages it needs to work like so with the url.

categories/Tops -> Would show soft tops and bottom tops
categories/Soft-Tops -> would show soft tops only
categories/External-Accessories -> Should show everything

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Did you use [tag:views] as tag because the question is about the Views module? If that is the case, make it clear in the question in what way you are using the Views module. Otherwise, if you added [tag:views] because the question is about displaying nodes, you are using the wrong tag.

Comment: This has originally been tagged with views.

Comment: Yes, but there was no reference to the Views module in the question body; that is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [`taxonomy_get_tree()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7.x) that you can use to fetch all the term IDs under a given parent ID. You can then call [`taxonomy_select_nodes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7.x) with an array of term IDs, which will return all nids that match that collection of tids.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an answer that could be done by actually using views. However, I am running out of time and if I can't seem to find anyone that knows how to do this, I might have to use your suggestion and just build a custom module to do it.